# Why recycler view only show first data only?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-binder

So I have 3 data on my firestore database, but when I run my app, it only show the first data only. I thought the binder will automatically read all the data and increase by itself like a loop. But turns out it stucks to only first index position. I thought I have implemented the recycler view correctly because there are no errors on my code.

I also even print a Log to check if I pass the username and score correctly to leaderboard adapter and it is correct. When I check the Log, it produced the desire output. Am I missing something on my implementation?

Comment: check your recyclerview item layout height

Comment: My recyclerview layout height already in wrap_content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check adapter root layout layout_height should be "wrap_content"

Comment: My recyclerview layout height already in wrap_content

Comment: Not  recyclerview layout height adapter xml root layout